# Connection error from GeoServer to PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql

The error message is as follows:

> Error creating data store, check the parameters. Error message: Unable to obtain connection: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The authentication type 10 is not supported. Check that you have configured the pg_hba.conf file to include the client's IP address or subnet, and that it is using an authentication scheme supported by the driver.)

It appeared at the time of creating a Data Warehouse.

Comment: This is an English language site. Please use English.

Comment: This seems to be more of a PostgreSQL topic, better researched in [dba.se]

Comment: `authentication type 10` is `scram-sha-256`. It looks like you are using an outdated driver

Answer (score 1):

The solution in my case was the following:

I modified the pg_hba file located in: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\data\pg_hba, changing the connection method from "scram-sha-256" to "trust" on all lines.

[image]

Comment: This is an English language site. Please use English

Comment: It would be helpful if you accept the answer.